# binding a mouse over event in jquery

Tags: jquery, events

My DOM looks like:

```
<body>  <div class="c1"> 
              <div class="c2">
              ...
              </div>
              <div class="c3">
                      <div class="thisone">....</div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="c1"> 
              <div class="c2">
              ...
              </div>
              <div class="c3">
                      <div class="thisone">....</div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="c1"> 
              <div class="c2">
              ...
              </div>
              <div class="c3">
                      <div class="thisone">....</div>
              </div>
        </div>
         </body>
```

The div element with class 'thisone' is hidden currently.

During a mouseover of the class c1, I want the div with 'thisone' to be visible, and hidden during a mouseout.

How can I do this using jQuery?  I want to drill down as much as possible to make it efficient but I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

Comment: If I mouse over a div on the 'thisone' for that div should be made visible?

Comment: @James Black - and he has never answered a question!

Comment: @jrhicks - wow that's quite a miracle to reach 2.5k rep without answering any questions =D

Comment: its not a miracle, it takes hard work to ask good questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surest and easiest way:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  $(".c1").hover(
     function(){
       // mouse in
       $(this).children(".thisone").stop().fadeIn(); // you can change fadeIn to show
     },
     function(){
       // mouse out
       $(this).children(".thisone").stop().fadeOut(); // you can change fadeOut to hide
     }
  );
});
```

Comment: if you try it out really quickly, you will know that stop() helps with responsiveness - this is because animation in jQuery are queued. You need to stop the current animation to continue the next to increase responsiveness.

Comment: To stop any animation currently occurring. You can have visual artifacts or incorrect functionality without using it.